# RegEx help to replace substring

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a String:

```
StartTime-2014-01-14 12:05:00-StartTime
```

The requirement is to replace the timestamp with current timestamp.

I tried the below code which is not giving me the expected output:

```
String st = "StartTime-2014-01-14 12:05:00-StartTime"; 
String replace = "StartTime-2014-01-14 13:05:00-StartTime"; 
Pattern COMPILED_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(st, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); 
Matcher matcher = COMPILED_PATTERN.matcher(DvbseContent); 
String f = matcher.replaceAll(replace);
```

Expected Output is:

```
StartTime-<Current_Time_stamp>-StartTime
```

Comment: What are `st`, `While_String`, `replace_with_timeStamp`?

Comment: Please post your complete code

Comment: String st = "StartTime-2014-01-14 12:05:00-StartTime";
  String replace = "StartTime-2014-01-14 13:05:00-StartTime";
  
  Pattern COMPILED_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(st,  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = COMPILED_PATTERN.matcher(DvbseContent);
  String f = matcher.replaceAll(replace);

Comment: You CANNOT use your input string as regex in `Pattern.compile`

Comment: You can replace whole string, no RegExp required: st = "StartTime-2014-01-14 13:05:00-StartTime"

Answer (score 0):

You could match it like this:

```
(StartTime-).*?(-StartTime)
```

and replace it with this (or similar):

```
"$1" + current_time_stamp + "$2"
```

---

[**Example Java Code:**](http://ideone.com/WckytI)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        java.util.Date timestamp = new java.util.Date();
        String search = "StartTime-2014-01-14 12:05:00-StartTime";
        String regex = "(StartTime-).*?(-StartTime)";
        String replacement = "$1"+ timestamp + "$2";
        String result = search.replaceAll(regex, replacement);

        System.out.println(result);
    };
};
```

Output:

> StartTime-Fri Feb 14 08:53:57 GMT 2014-StartTime

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of Regex, you can just use indexOf and lastIndexOf:

```
String f = "StartTime-2014-01-14 12:05:00-StartTime";
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                  .format(new java.util.Date());
String newString = f.substring(0, f.indexOf("-") + 1) 
                + timestamp 
                + f.substring(f.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

Output:
StartTime-2014-02-10 12:52:47-StartTime